# fread is signalling EOF prematurely with a binary file

Tags: c, io, fread

I'm a newcomer to C. I'm attempting to make my own version of `base64`; the program takes input from stdin and outputs its base64 equivalent to stdout. While testing my program against a binary file, I noticed that `fread`-ing from stdin seemed to be returning a short count early before actually reaching EOF.

Here is the relevant portion of my main method:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char base64_buffer[BASE64_BUFFER];

    while (1)
    {
        TRACE_PUTS("Reading in data from stdin...");
        size_t read = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin); /* Read the data in using fread(3) */

        /* Process the buffer */

        TRACE_PRINTF("Amount read: %zu\n", read);
        TRACE_PUTS("Beginning base64 encode of buffer");
        size_t encoded = base64_encode(buffer, read, base64_buffer, sizeof(base64_buffer));

        /* Write the data to stdout */
        TRACE_PUTS("Writing data to standard output");
        ...

        if (read < sizeof(buffer))
        {
            break; /* We reached EOF or had an error during the read */
        }
    }

    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
        /* Handle errors */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "There was a problem reading from the file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    puts(""); /* Output a newline before finishing */

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the main loop calls `fread` every iteration on stdin into a buffer, then at the end checks if the amount read is less than the size of the buffer. If it is, we assume there was either an error (in which case 0 was returned) or EOF was reached, and exit from the loop.

I am assuming that it is OK to check `read` to be `< sizeof(buffer)`, rather than just `!= 0`, based on this quote from fread's manpage:

> On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.  **If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).**

This implies that if the full buffer is not read into, then EOF is reached.

With that established, this is the trace I get when I run my app against `cat /bin/echo`:

```
$ cat /bin/echo | bin/base64 >/dev/null # only view the trace output
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:23: Reading in data from stdin...
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:28: Amount read: 600
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:29: Beginning base64 encode of buffer
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:43: Writing data to standard output
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:23: Reading in data from stdin...
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:28: Amount read: 600
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:29: Beginning base64 encode of buffer
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:43: Writing data to standard output
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:23: Reading in data from stdin...
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:28: Amount read: 600
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:29: Beginning base64 encode of buffer
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:43: Writing data to standard output
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:23: Reading in data from stdin...
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:28: Amount read: 569
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:29: Beginning base64 encode of buffer
TRACE: C:/Users/James/Code/c/base64/main.c:43: Writing data to standard output

$
```

And here is how large `/bin/echo` actually is:

```
$ cat /bin/echo | wc -c
28352
```

So as you can see, the whole file is 28352 bytes long, but my app is only reading in about ~2400 of them before it stops. Any idea why? Does `fread` handle null terminators specially?

I am using MinGW-w64 with GCC if that helps; thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you on Windows?  Yes, the pathname starts `C:` so you are.  You've probably got a Control-Z (`'\x1A'` or `'\32'`) character in the file.  It (the Windows C run-time, and hence your program) won't treat standard input as a binary file unless you tweak it somehow, so the Control-Z marks the end of the input.

One possible 'somehow' to tweak the mode is [`_set_fmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61dstksf.aspx).  However, it is more likely that you need [`_setmode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx):

```
_setmode(fileno(stdin), O_BINARY);
```

I reserve judgement on whether that's the best or only method for doing so.  You can research the manuals as well as I can.  I have no way to test that `fileno()` — or perhaps `_fileno()` in the Microsoft world — is available.